# Find $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,{\rm d}t$ where $f(x)= 1/(x-5)^2 + x^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Given the function $f(x)= 1/(x-5)^2 + x^3$, find $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,{\rm d}t$. I'm not sure how to go about this problem since my function is in terms of $x$ and not $t$.

Comment: This means the antiderivative of $f(x)$ which vanishes at $0$. A Riemann integral depends on the bounds, not on the integration variable – exactly like $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ depends on $n$, not on $k$, which is a dummy variable.

Comment: The $x$ in $f(x)$ is just the variable name telling us that $f$ is a function of a single variable. Take $x=t$ to get $f(t) = 1/(t-5)^2 + t^3$.

Comment: @kms1661 If you do not want your question down voted you should explain what you attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $f(t)= \frac{1}{(t-5)^2} + t^3.$

Thus, $F(x)=\displaystyle \int_\limits 0^x \left(\frac{1}{(t-5)^2} + t^3\right)\,{\rm d}t=[-(t-5)^{-1}+\frac{t^4}{4}]_0^x=-\frac{1}{x-5}+\frac{x^4}{4}-[-\frac{1}{0-5}+\frac{0^4}{4}]=-\frac{1}{x-5}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: Thank you. So what is the difference between taking the integral of f(x) and this F(x)? Just the constant?

Comment: The integral of F(x) doing the same procedure for f(x) again. You will need the constant for the integral of F(x) because it is an indefinite integral..

Comment: So the only difference between finding this F(x) and the integral of f(x) is that F(x) results in a specific function and the integral of f(x) is a family of functions? Sorry if that's confusing. I'm new at this but I think it's pretty interesting and just want to understand it better.

Comment: You have it correct except, the integral of F(x) is a family of functions.